# Inexplicable Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

In my attempt to define an n-dimensional Vector class, I've run into a 'syntax' error when defining multiplication that I really don't know how to get around...

```
class Vector:
def __init__(self, v):
    if len(v)==0: self.v = (0,0)
    else: self.v = v

 #bunch of functions in between here....

 def __mul__(self, other):
    if type(other) == Vector:
        if len(self.v) != len(other.v):
            raise AssertionError

    dotprod = 0
    for i in range(len(self.v)):
        dotprod += self.v[i+1] * other.v[i+1]
    return dotprod

elif type(other) in [int, float]:

    new = []
    for component in self.v:
        new.append(component*other)
    return Vector(tuple(new))
else:
    raise AssertionError
```

the error is as follows:

```
File "<ipython-input-52-50a37fd0919a>", line 40
elif type(other) in [int, float]:
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've played around with the indentation and the elif statement numerous times, and I really can't see what the issue is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To which of the `if` statements shall this `elif` belong to? It must be indented the same way as the accompanying `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is definitely an indentation error. I think this is what you intended:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    if type(other) == Vector:
        if len(self.v) != len(other.v):
            raise AssertionError

        dotprod = 0
        for i in range(len(self.v)):
            dotprod += self.v[i+1] * other.v[i+1]
        return dotprod

    elif type(other) in [int, float]:

        new = []
        for component in self.v:
            new.append(component*other)
        return Vector(tuple(new))
    else:
        raise AssertionError
```

This puts the `elif` at the same indentation level as the `if`.

Comment: yeah everything was actually pretty jumbled, thanks for your help